# Как программно отключить нажатия в RadioGroup

Tags: android, radiobutton

Как отключить программно RadioGroup, чтобы находящиеся в ней RadioButton-ы не переключались. Пробовал применять к группе isEnabled=false, но это не помогает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно отключать каждую радиокнопку в группе:

```
for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
    radioGroup.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
}
```

таким образом вы переберете все кнопки.

Answer (score 3):

Трюк состоит в том, чтобы перебрать все дочерние View (в данном случае:) CheckBox-ы вызвать `setEnabled(boolean)`

Нечто подобное должно сработать:

```
final RadioGroup rg1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
CheckBox ck1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

for(int i = 0; i < rg1.getChildCount(); i++){
    ((RadioButton)rg1.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(checked);
}
```